# format percentage SQL - EXCEL ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I am trying to add percentage values to cells in EXCEL using SSIS

Issue I have is they are not formatted to percentage

current calculation

```
cast(100*sum([OrdersCompleted]) / count(id) as decimal(10,1)) as percentage
```

example value is 75.0

I want to format this with the 'P' (not working very well)

```
FORMAT(above calculation here, 'P')
```

to 75.0%

what is the best way to do this please?

please help

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
FORMAT(cast(100*sum([OrdersCompleted]) / count(id) as decimal(10,1)) + "%")
```

Output will be:

> 75.0 %

Comment: hi sorry this does not work, format needs to be please like 75.0%

Comment: I think it is simple just replace "P" with "%". I  edited the answer hope it helps

Comment: @Hadi : Agreed.